# Terminal Server : shadow a session using AxMSTCLib

Tags: service, terminal, terminal-services, rdp

I'm trying to "shadow" a session within a session opened through AxMSTCLib (using c# app), but I get ejected. Is this normal with TS2008 ?

If so, as anyone ressource explaining how to open a shawod rdp session using managed code ?

Regards,

Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programmatically start remote control of a session, you can do so using the [Cassia library](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/) -- download the latest trunk build from the project's [build server](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=bt95&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts) (login as a guest) and use the ITerminalServicesSession.StartRemoteControl method.

I have had issues with sessions being disconnected when ending remote control (see [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverTS/thread/28a26bdc-7894-4695-9024-f147a5c4563f)), but I'm not sure if that's what you are referring to.